# Why Geocoder from Google Maps is returning japanese character?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a method with body like this:

```
Address address = new Geocoder(context).getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 5).get(0);
return address.getThoroughfare() + ", " + address.getSubThoroughfare() + ", " + address.getSubLocality();
```

When I print the result, the value of `address.getSubLocality()` shows a string in Japanese.

Why this happnes?

And how can I fix this?

Thank you!

**EDIT**

My full example project:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    EditText ed1, ed2;
    TextView tv1;
    Button bt1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed1);
        ed2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed2);
        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt1);

        ed1.setText("-23.50282");
        ed2.setText("-46.84905");

        bt1.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public static String getAddressFromLocation(Context context, Double latitude, Double longitude) throws IOException {
        Address address = new Geocoder(context, Locale.ENGLISH).getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 5).get(0);
        return address.getThoroughfare() + ", " + address.getSubThoroughfare() + ", " + address.getSubLocality() + " - " + address.getAdminArea();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String address = "Street";
        if (v.getId() == R.id.bt1) {
            try {
                address = getAddressFromLocation(this, Double.parseDouble(ed1.getText().toString()), Double.parseDouble(ed2.getText().toString()));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            tv1.setText(address);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you look at the address, may be the address itself has weird characters in it. May be try some other locations.

Comment: I've already try, and the others are correct. I thought there was an way to force the address be shown in non-japanese characteres ever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It returns that way because that's how it's labeled in [Google Maps](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=-23.50282,%20-46.84905&hl=en&ll=-23.506976,-46.848536&spn=0.032467,0.055747&sll=30.46714,-84.256856&sspn=0.488261,0.891953&t=h&z=15&iwloc=A&layer=c&cbll=-23.502742,-46.848994&panoid=T8RPc6NBj_jBMD-dhqkqlA&cbp=12,191.75,,0,12.47). The Japanese characters you see(`アウファヴィーレ`) are the representation for [Alphaville](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphaville,_S%C3%A3o_Paulo), a development company in that area.

Why someone labeled it in Japanese, I don't know. There's not much you can do about it, though. Other locations nearby aren't labeled this way.

Comment: Yeah. That is true. I've already looked the addres by this way. The strange is that Google Maps returns non-japanese characteres for anothers residence numbers at this same street.

Comment: Like I said, I have no clue why someone labeled a Brazilian neighborhood in Japanese. Unless it's a (very) obscure reference to [Alphaville - Big in Japan](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GyGqk3Uac_Y) that someone snuck in there, but even that's a stretch.

Comment: Yes. I will choose your answer, because my question aks "why", and you give a good answer to this, but I am disappointed for don't be able to resolve this issue. =/
Anyway, thank you!

Comment: I think the only way to resolve it would be to contact Google and ask them why it's labeled that way. They may change it, assuming there's not a valid reason. You could scan for Japanese characters in your code and strip them, but that might be too much work considering this is probably the edgiest of edge cases.

Comment: I will try contact them

Comment: This appears to be a common problem. I've seen this same issue when running lat/lng on SF and in Mountain View CA (ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19596477/japanese-characters-in-my-json-google-maps-api-results). Definitely not right and messes up en-US apps trying to consume data.

Answer (score -1):

The constructor of the [Geocoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#Geocoder%28android.content.Context,%20java.util.Locale%29) class takes a [Locale](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html) Object as parameter. With this you can have the output in any supported language. If you don't set a explicit local, as in your snippet, Locale.getDefault() will be used by default.

```
Address address = new Geocoder(context, Locale.ENGLISH)
        .getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 5).get(0);
```

Comment: Even if I set my location to English, Google yet returns the result in japaneses characteres. I've updated my question with the full code.