# Japanese characters in my JSON Google Maps API Results?

Tags: json, google-maps

I'm based in USA and make a call to: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=xxx,xxx&sensor=false and see most data in english and then this. (note; xxx is actually a real lat & lng, just removed here).

Anyone know what this is and why its here? How do I get rid of irrelevant results?

```
{
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "サン・ホセ＝サニーベール＝サンタ・クララ",
           "short_name" : "サン・ホセ＝サニーベール＝サンタ・クララ",
           "types" : [ "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "California",
           "short_name" : "CA",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "United States",
           "short_name" : "US",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "United States, California, サン・ホセ＝サニーベール＝サンタ・クララ",
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why Geocoder from Google Maps is returning japanese character?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059948/why-geocoder-from-google-maps-is-returning-japanese-character)

Comment: Cheers Dr. Molle, yes same issue. Thanks for the link.