# How to get address from google map by custom language

Tags: android, google-places-api

I can get the current address from google map's api (Google Place Picker). but it returns strings as English language.

now, How can I change default language google place picker?

Is it possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27221173/4148757

Comment: Did u check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35720426/how-to-change-language-of-placepicker-in-android)

Comment: add language at end of url `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=35.706172,51.316568&sensor=true&language=ar`  [laguage support](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#languagesupport)